# Passing arguments to addplot inside groupplots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

My question is about basic usage of `pgfplots` and `groupplots`. Here's a simple example plotting powers of x:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={group size=2 by 2},
    ]
    \nextgroupplot \addplot {x};
    \nextgroupplot \addplot {x^2};
    \nextgroupplot \addplot {x^3};
    \nextgroupplot \addplot {x^4};

  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following after running it through pdflatex:

[image: groupplots example plotting powers of x]

Now, say that I want to make all my plots red (or thick, or whatever -- I want to pass arguments to all the plots in the group). It feels like I should be able to do something along the lines of

```
  \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={group size=2 by 2},
      red,
    ]
```

But that gives me a `I do not know the key '/pgfplots/red' and I am going to ignore it` error. I know I can get around this by adding `[red]` after every `addplot`, or maybe by using `\def\mystyle{red}` and `\addplot[\mystyle]`, but that seems repetitive and inefficient. Are there any nicer ways of doing this?

PS: I am not very knowledgeable about the inner workings of pgfplots, so I'll appreciate if any answer can also explain *why* this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to use a cycle list (or a multi cycle list). For `\addplot[very thick, red, only marks]` you are telling pgfplot what to do on the current line/plot and nothing about what happens next. What you are asking about is to change the default plotting for all lines within a plot. This is what cycle lists do. They make the first `\addplot` red, the next blue, and so on. You can do this with `\nextgroupplot[cycle multiindex* list = {very thick\nextlist red\nextlist only marks\nextlist}]` or you can default for all the plots in the groupplot.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={group size=2 by 2},
      cycle multiindex* list = {very thick\nextlist red\nextlist only marks\nextlist}
  ]
    \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
    \nextgroupplot[cycle list = {red, blue}] \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
    \nextgroupplot \addplot[green] {x}; \addplot {x^2};
    \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Why is the `\nextlist` needed?

Comment: @PedroMediano `cycle multiindex* list`  lets you define separate cycle lists of different length. For example if you do `cycle multiindex* list={very thick,dashed \nextlist red,blue,green,cyan}` then the first plot has `very thick,red`, the next has `dashed,blue`, the third has `very thick green` and the fourth has `dashed,cyan`. You can read about cycle lists in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf), section 4.7.7.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Cool, thanks. So, just to clarify: multiple `addplot`s in the same `nextgroupplot` will iterate through the list(s), and starting a new `nextgroupplot` will bring all lists back to the start. Therefore my original problem can be solved with a multi cycle list in which every list has one element (as in the sample code in the answer). Thanks!